# How to find polymorphic relation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, polymorphism

```
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :rulable, :polymorphic => true
end
class foo < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :items, :as => rulable
end
class bar < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :items, :as => rulable
end
```

What is the best way to find items belonging to a foo? I'm currently using something like this:

```
f = Foo.find 1
Item.find_by_rulable_id_and_rulable_type(f, 'Foo')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following is semantically equivalent and much easier to read and type.

```
f = Foo.find 1
f.items
```